# Python - create next file

Tags: python, file, loops, python-2.7, text

I am writing a small script. The script creates `.txt` files. I do not want to replace existing files. So what I want python to do is to check if the file already exists. If it does  not it can proceed. If the file does exists I would like python to increment the name and than check again if the file already exists. If the file does not already exist python may create it.
EXAMPLE:
current dir has these files in it:

`file_001.txt`

`file_002.txt`

I want python to see that the two files exists and make the next file:

`file_003.txt`

creating files can be done like this:

```
f = open("file_001.txt", "w")
f.write('something')
f.close()
```

[checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-using-python) if a file exists:

```
import os.path
os.path.isfile(fname)
```

Comment: `import os; os.path.exist` might be helpful.

Comment: I think I will be able to answer my own question actually. I could use a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that will get the job done, I answered it myself.

import os.path

```
def next_file(filename):
    """
    filename: string. Name only of the current file
    returns: string. The name of the next file to be created
    assumes the padding of the file is filename_001.txt The number of starting zeros does   not not matter
    """
    fill_exists = True
    current = '001'
    padding = len(current)  # length of digits
    file = '{}_{}.txt'.format(filename, current)  # the actual name of the file, inlc. extension
    while fill_exists:
        if not os.path.isfile(file):  # if the file does not already exist
            f = open(file, 'w')  # create file
            f.write(filename)
            f.close()
            return 'Created new file: {}_{}.txt'.format(filename, current)  # shows the name of file just created
        else:
            current = str(int(current)+1).zfill(padding)  # try the next number
            file = '{}_{}.txt'.format(filename, current)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check whether it's both a file and that it exist then use `os.path.exists` along with `os.path.isfile`. Or else just the former seems suffice. Following might help:

```
import os.path as op
print op.exists(fname) and op.isfile(fname)
```

or just `print op.exists(fname)`

Comment: I also want python to find out which is the next file to be created in the sequence and create it.